# Why is $F'(x) = 2x·\tan(x^2)-\tan x$ if $F(x) = \int_{x}^{x^2}\tan u\, \mathrm du$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $F'(x)$ if 
$$F(x) = \int_{x}^{x^2}\tan u\, \mathrm du$$

I tried to do this by the change of variables formula and hence,
$$F(x) = \int_{x}^{x^2}\tan u\, \mathrm du=\int_{\sqrt x}^{x}\tan x^2\,2x \mathrm dx.$$

Thus by the second fundamental theorem
$$ F'(x)=2x\tan x^2.$$

But the given answer is 
$$ F'(x)=2x\tan x^2-\tan x.$$

I don't understand why there is the $-\tan x$ part. I've just learnt this part, so a step-by-step guide is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the fundamental theorem of calculus: 
If $g$ is continuous, then

$$\int_a^b g(x) dx = G(b)-G(a)$$

With $G'(x) = g(x)$

So, let $g(x) = \tan(x)$, you have

$$F(x) = \int_x^{x^2} g(x) dx = G(x^2)-G(x)$$

This means that by the chain rule

$$F'(x) = 2xG'(x^2)-G'(x)$$

Hence

$$F'(x) = 2xg(x^2)-g(x)=2x \tan(x^2) - \tan(x)$$

Comment: Thanks! But can you point out what's wrong with my using FT2?

Comment: @IvanH.Jc : What's wrong in your solution is that **both** bound of the integral depend on $x$, but you only considered the upper bound as variable

Comment: This is not the fundamental theorem of calculus, it is just the Barrow rule. The english wikipedia is not too good in this point.